# angular2 ag-grid filter, sort and paging

Tags: angular, filter, paging, ag-grid

I implemented ag-grid paging,sort and filtering. paging works fine but filtering ad sort works only in a same page. How both filter and sort works on whole pages?

```
  <ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid style="width: 100%; height=450px" class="ag-common" #list 
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [columnDefs]="columns"
            [enableColResize]="true"
            [enableSorting]="true"
            [enableFilter]="true"
            [groupHeaders]="true"
            [suppressRowClickSelection]="true"
            [showToolPanel]="showToolPanel"
            [datasource]="dataSource"
             rowModelType = "pagination"
             rowHeight="26"
             colWidth="100"
             rowSelection="multiple"
             (gridReady)="gridReady"
             (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)">
  </ag-grid-ng2> 



in a TS file
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions> {
  onGridSizeChanged: () => {
    this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by whole pages? Are you using pagination or virtual scrolling here?

Comment: yes. but I solved this problem. This page helped me. https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/587